# Avoid domain name in variable view when debugging golang code in vscode with remote import path?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

My Go code use a package from github.com; hence a import path with a full url. When I debug this program, I find that all variables from this package are qualified with the full url, which occupies a lot of valuable space in debug view and make thing very hard to read. Is there a way to get rid of the full url part?

I tried aliasing the package but still doesn't help, i.e.

```
import a_pkg_name "github.com/a/very/long/url/to/the/package"
```

Comment: which package do you want to use?

Comment: No.  The fully qualified package name is always used as far as I know.  Are you setting package-scoped variables?

Comment: this is normal, and i would expect that as a debugger user. This helps distinguish between two +/- identical types with the same name and package name but different package path. Maybe they could improve the UI to show that on mouse over, but, what do i know about that debugger, i ve never used it : / Anyways, this had little to do on SO i am afraid, consider rising a ticket on the appropriate package repo issue list.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP should rise a ticket on the appropriate repo issue list.